# docker-compose and graceful Celery shutdown

Tags: django, docker, celery, docker-compose

I've been wondering about and searching for solutions for this and I didn't find any.

I'm running Celery in a container built with docker-compose. My container is configured like this:

```
celery:
  build: .
  container_name: cl01
  env_file: ./config/variables.env
  entrypoint:
    - /celery-entrypoint.sh
  volumes:
    - ./django:/django
  depends_on:
    - web
    - db
    - redis
  stop_grace_period: 1m
```

And my entrypoint script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Wait for django
sleep 10
su -m dockeruser -c "celery -A myapp worker -l INFO"
```

Now, if I run `docker-compose stop`, I would like to have a warm (graceful) shutdown, giving Celery the provided 1 minute (`stop_grace_period`) to finish already started tasks. However `docker-compose stop` seems to kill Celery straight away. Celery should also log that it is asked to shut down gracefully, but I don't see anything but an abrupt stop to my task logs.

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to change to make Celery shut down gracefully?

edit:
Suggested answer below about providing the `--timeout` parameter to `docker-compose stop` does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 7):

You need to mark `celery` process with `exec`, this way celery process will have the same ID as docker command and docker will be able to send a SIGTERM signal to it and gracefully close celery process.

```
# should be the last command in script
exec celery -A myapp worker -l INFO
```

Answer (score 2):

My experience implementing graceful shutdown for `celery` workers spawned by `supervisord` inside a `docker` container.

### Supervisord part

***supervisord.conf***

```
...
[supervisord]
    ...
    nodaemon=true     # run supervisord in the foreground
[include]
    files=celery.conf # path to the celery config file
```

Set `nodaemon=true` so that we can start it as a background process from the entrypoint script later.

***celery.conf***

```
[group:celery_workers] 
    programs=one, two
[program:one]
    ...
    command=celery -A backend --config=celery.py worker -n worker_one --pidfile=/var/log/celery/worker_one.pid --pool=gevent --concurrency=10 --loglevel=INFO
    killasgroup=true
    stopasgroup=true
    stopsignal=TERM
    stopwaitsecs=600
[program:two]
    ...
    # similar to the previous one
```

The configuration file above is responsible for starting a `group` of workers each running in a separate `process` within a `group`. I'd like to stop on a `stopwaitsecs` section value. Let's see what the documentation tells us about it:

> This parameter sets the number of seconds to wait for the OS to return
> a SIGCHLD to supervisord after the program has been sent a
> stopsignal. If this number of seconds elapses before supervisord
> receives a SIGCHLD from the process, supervisord will attempt to kill
> it with a final SIGKILL.

If `stopwaitsecs`>`stop_grace_period` specified for your service in a `docker-compose` file then you'll be getting `SIGKILL` from your `docker`. Make sure
`stopwaitsecs`<`stop_grace_period`, otherwise all running tasks get interrupted by `docker`.

### Entrypoint script part

***entrypoint.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

# safety switch, exit script if there's error.
set -e

on_close(){
    echo "Signal caught..."
    echo "Supervisor is stopping processes gracefully..."

    # cleanup all pid files
    rm worker_one.pid
    rm worker_two.pid

    supervisorctl stop celery_workers:

    echo "All processes have been stopped. Exiting..."
    exit 1
}

start_supervisord(){
    supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
}

# start trapping signals (docker sends `SIGTERM` for shutdown)
trap on_close SIGINT SIGTERM SIGKILL

start_supervisord &   # start supervisord in a background
SUPERVISORD_PID=$!    # PID of the last background process started
wait $SUPERVISORD_PID
EXIT_STATUS=$?        # the exit status of the last command executed
```

The script above consists of:

- registering a cleanup function `on_close`
- starting `supervisord`'s process group in a background
- registering the last background process's `PID` and waiting for it to finish

### Docker part

***docker-compose.yml***

```
...
services:
  celery:
    ...
    stop_grace_period: 15m30s
    entrypoint: [/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh]
```

The only setting worth mentioning here is `entrypoint` form declaration. In our case better to use `exec` form. It starts an executable script in a process with `PID` 1 and doesn't create any subprocesses as `shell` form does. `SIGTERM` from `docker stop <container>` gets propagated to an executable which traps it and performs all cleaning and closing logic.

Answer (score 1):

Via [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/)

```
Usage: stop [options] [SERVICE...]

Options:
-t, --timeout TIMEOUT      Specify a shutdown timeout in seconds (default: 10).
```

Try with timeout set to 60 seconds at least.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Funnily enough, Celery, Celery Beat and Flower are the first things that are shut down within seconds. nginx, django, redis etc all take their time and close after 60 seconds..

And a question: I thought this was exactly what the `stop_grace_period` parameter in the docker-compose.yml was for? So you wouldn't need to set the timeout when running the bash command.

Comment: Well, yes, but you set it only for celery service, when setting timeout while running `docker-compose stop` should work for all containers. I don't know why it shuts down that way though.

Answer (score -4):

Try using this:

```
docker-compose down
```

Comment: Posts here are required to be in English. I "translated" (very roughly anyway) it for you this time because it was such a small part of the answer (and the rest appears to be useful) - but please keep that in mind next time you post an answer, or a question for that matter.

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.